# @angular/google-maps Change marker color

Tags: google-maps-markers, angular-google-maps, angular11

I am using [google-maps](https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/google-maps/google-map) for Angular, and I can't find how to change the color of the marker. I have different coordinates and I wish to color each one separately.

For now I am using :

```
        const marker = {
      position: {
        lat: parseFloat(site.lat),
        lng: parseFloat(site.lng),
      },
      icon: "https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/full/images/beachflag.png",
      id: site.id,
      title: site.address,
      label: {
        color: 'red',
        text: site.contractCode,
      }
    };
```

I tried to pass an object with url attribute to icon, and a string, but none worked.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you use:

```
<map-marker class="markerR" #marker="mapMarker" *ngFor="let unaalerta of listado"
                        [position]="unaalerta.Marker"
                        [options]="{icon: { url:'assets/images/{{unaalerta.icono}}' }, zIndex: 100}"
```

Comment: Thanks,
this works, but I had to pass the icon urls from the backend to get over an async issue. Apparently the map attributed the last marker's icon in my array to all of them when I built options in a loop for the markers.